# What is the recommended approach to using and storing credentials for Robot Framework Tests

Tags: python, passwords, automated-tests, robotframework, credentials

Most tests are run using some kind of credentials or keys to access the system under test. When the same suite of tests is run against several different environments, this management of credentials becomes more important.

Presently we are using a Robot Framework variable file to store them locally. But this requires a file per environment, or a single file with a master switch. This works, but is not a secure solution. For this reason I'm seeking your input.

Several solutions seem to be out there, HashiCorp's Vault being one of them, that help with this management of credentials and seek your feedback on what works for you and why. If possible within the context of Robot Framework but generic solutions with Python will work too.

Comment: Could just store them in a database somewhere (unencrypted) and pull it like that using the DatabaseLibrary... I mean, it's not secure but at least you don't have to store them locally per testing instance... http://franz-see.github.io/Robotframework-Database-Library/api/0.5/DatabaseLibrary.html

Comment: Could store the details in resource file and import that into script as `'Resource    ResourceFile'`, this can be another solution

Comment: @SaradaAkurathi whether I use a resource file, or a variable file (as I do today) is from a security point of view the same. They're both unencrypted, decentralised storage of credentials. Something I'm trying to prevent.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using excel with Python and then import that as a keyword to your RF.
Clear instructions are given here in this blog post, I found that they are suitable for your req: https://blog.aspose.com/2021/06/01/encrypt-and-decrypt-excel-files-in-python/